# VideoJS - Subtitle/Caption track showing twice in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, video.js

2 questions:

1) I've been working on integration `video.js` with `colorbox` (for a `lightbox` display) and it is working fine, but when I add the subtitle or captions track info:

```
<track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles/sample.vtt" srclang="en" 
label="English" default>
```

In Chrome I get the subtitle/captions track overlaid twice.

[image: http://s9.postimage.org/hnuj82vzx/screenshot.png]

when I open up the dev tools on it I can "see" the track which uses the smaller text at the bottom, but I have no idea where the larger text is coming from. So question: Is this other track a function of Chrome being "helpful"?

In FF it works fine, with just the single caption/subtitle track appearing.

2) Any idea when the metadata track support will be introduced?

Answer (score 2):

You have 'default' in the track. Do you want the subtitles showing by default or do you want to wait until the user triggers them? If you remove default it should stop Chrome from showing the second version.

Video.js [removes the tracks](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/src/player.js#L64) from the video tag when it reads them in, but apparently that's not enough for Chrome and it will still pick them up and show them. We'll have to add in something to also disable tracks in the native player.

I added an issue you can follow. https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/issues/259

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code into a web page in script element

```
var myvideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
for (var i = 0, j = myvideo .length; i < j; i++) {
    myvideo[i].textTracks[0].mode = "hidden";
};
```